# How to save the primary key of one table into another table in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I am using a database-first approach.

I have 2 tables in the database - `Employee` and `Department`.

I made a popup registration form for "Add New Employee" in that I am including a dropdown which is populated by a list of `depart_name` from the `Department` table. But while saving, I want to save the `DepartmentID` instead of the `Depart_Name` related to selected option into employee table as foreign key.

[HomeController_pic_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH7Hb.jpg)

[HomeController_pic_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPJNP.jpg)

[HomeController_pic_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5XIm.jpg)

[Save.cshtml_pic_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6Zng.jpg)

[Save.cshtml_pic_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsiA7.jpg)

[Department.cs pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6ErX.jpg)

[Employee.cs Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZ2Vf.jpg)

[MyModel.Context pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCdst.jpg)

Comment: Try to write your code in question so someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

As your question is not clear well, but as far as i understand, i'm giving you a possible solution.
Why don't you change your department dropdown generation Code a little bit. Define your value and text field. Then you'll get access to `department_id` as value.

Your need to have a dropdown model i.e `DropdownDataModel` if your Departments table has more columns than `id` and `name`

```
public class DropdownDataModel{
    public virtual int value { get; set; }
    public virtual string text { get; set; }
}
```

Then generate a list of department from your table data

```
public ActionResult YourFunc(){
    //Your rest of codes
    Viewbag.Departments = _db.Departments.Select(x => new DropdownDataModel{ value = x.id, text = department_name }).toList();
}
```

Then Build a dropdown with that data from view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.department_id, new SelectList(ViewBag.Departments , "value", "text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Well of course your `Employee` model must have `department_id` as a field and you've created your database as it is and build relation

Comment: I have Added Some more sc shoot, of MyModel.context ,department.cs and employee.cs.  Please Guide me where i am going wrong

Comment: Build your dropdown as i've mentioned in my answer. Look above, you've pointed every field of your form to your `Employee` model field except `department_id`. You need to use `DropdownListFor` helper in order to get your selected dept Id. `@Html.DropdownList` wont help you in this scenario.